# How to use the Print queue to avoid dropping pages

Tags: c#, excel, pdf, printing

OK,

I'm printing some stuff for work from C# using COM Interop with Office 2007 and BullZip PDF 7.1.1007.

The issue I'm having is that if I don't tell the program to sleep for 2500 milliseconds, then the PDF printer drops pages.  Which is weird.

I'm wondering if anyone else has experienced this issue.  I will post the code if that helps.

Comment: There are a lot of threads about this problem in their support forum. See for example http://www.bullzip.com/phpBB/viewtopic.php?f=16&t=7188&start=0&st=0&sk=t&sd=a&hilit=sleep